# How to move data between sides in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a list inside server side, I want to move it to client side, How?
When It's successfully moved, How to display it in my dataviewgrid ? Thanks

Comment: show some code to understanding propose of what you exactly need to do...

Answer (score 0):

You can have 3 different ways to acheive your goal.
1- develope web method on code behind and call it through ajax from client side method and in this method when you get result on success pass it to datagrid view
2-save list on serverside hidden field and get on client side.
3-you can call your list on client side page via  <%=mylist%>
On client side aspx page.

Mark as answer